# Download file from FTP server by passing file name as regular expression in vbscript

Tags: ftp

Am facing an issue, i wanted to download a file using regular expression from the server. the file name : TEST_123456-2014-17-10-12-14-59-result.xls will appear in the server,but i can use file creation date and time except seconds to find the file in the server.

but the question arises here seconds always vary from application to server ,so i want to make seconds as regular expression. expected format: TEST_123456-2014-17-10-12-14-.*-result.xls

i tried the above format but ,server returning with error as "File was not found"

is there any alternative way to pass seconds as regular expression.

please assist me in here, to see best solution. more over am using vbscript.

Comment: Please can any one help me ..its urgent and blocked my release activity.

Comment: Got resolved ..myself..thanks for all.solution is: TEST_123456-2014-17-10-12-14*result.xls

Answer (score 0):

issue has got resolved ..by myself..thanks for all.
solution is: TEST_123456-2014-17-10-12-14*result.xls